# Delphi - removing objects (frames) from VertScrollBox and add another ones

Tags: android, user-interface, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

Iam making an android app with Delphi Berlin. My 'gui' layout contains VertScrollBox. From code, in loop I add into that VertScrollBox some frames.
Sample code :

```
begin
  for I := 0 to List.Count - 1 do begin
    frameTmp := TFrameDetails.Create(Self);
    with frameTmp do begin         
      Name := Self.Name + '_FrameDetails_' + IntToStr(I);
      // rest of code to set properties
    end;
    VertScrollBox.AddObject(frameTmp);
    FCurrentFrames.Add(frameTmp); // add that frame to the ObjectList too, to remove it later..
  end;
end;
```

All works fine. In other procedure, I need to 'reload' VertScrollBox content - remove / clear frames inside it and add others. Code which remove frames:

```
for I := 0 to FCurrentFrames.Count -1 do begin
  VertScrollBox.RemoveObject(FCurrentFrames[I]);
end;
FCurrentFrames.Clear;
Application.ProcessMessages;
```

At this point I have a little problem - new frames are displayed in wrong order. If I have 10 frames, after reload displayed order is always 1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2. First frame is OK, rest is displayed in reserve order, doesnt matter how many frames. Frame align is set to Top.

Is there a solution to remove current frames from VertScrollBox witchout using another ObjectList (FCurrentFrames) ? Also, what I need to change / add to display new frames in correct order ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried InsertObject rather than AddObject? Also, once you have frames in right order RemoveObject( index : integer ) is supported.

Comment: I tryed InsertObject but it gains 'Out of range exception' when add 3rd frame (indexes: 0, 1, 2). I dont know why. Already solved my problem - Align := Top was a culprit. Just set it to none and calculate X,Y position manually from code. Thanks ;)